# Callable statement error while accessing sp

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am getting the error `ordinal binding and named binding cannot be combined`, when I try to call stored procedure from my java class.

My stored procedure will return some list of records

Below is my piece of java code:

```
CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
dbConnection = getDBConnection();
callableStatement = (CallableStatement) dbConnection.prepareCall("{call UPDATE_RQST_STATUS_SP(?)}");
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
callableStatement.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems good.

But I am afraid there is some bug in earlier oracle drivers.

You should upgrade to 10.1.0.3 or later JDBC driver.

Here you have it: [Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.4) JDBC Drivers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html)

Comment: @user1719212: `ojdbc14.jar` is intended for Java **1.4**, that is almost certainly not an up-to-date driver. Also are you really still using Oracle 10.x?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yeah exactly, he needs to shift to the latest version of the drivers

Comment: @GingerHead using he latest driver really helps and makes a lot of drifference!!

Comment: @Oliver nice to hear it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your stored procedure as follows and make sure you are using latest JDBC drivers for Oracle.

```
callablestatement = 
             connection.prepareCall("begin ? :=UPDATE_RQST_STATUS_SP(?); end;");
callablestatement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
callablestatement.execute();
resultSet = ((OracleCallableStatement)callablestatement).getCursor(1);
```

[Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chseven.htm#CACJDIAC) regarding calling PLSQL procedure or function from Java